Martingale property of the CEV model
I am a bit confused about the martingale property of the CEV model. Given $dS(t)=σS(t)^βdW(t)$, is $S$ a martingale for values of $β<1$?

Adding some more details to your question would be helpful.

Ito integrals are martingales. I guess the problem for beta>1 is the square of process has an infinite integral so the limits you use to prove this don't follow. The square integral is relevant because it is the variance of the ito integral.
It is intuitive because all of Ito's work relies on quadratic variation converging almost surely to $t$. If process is not square integrable, it's vol is infinite and thus it's quadratic var. does not converge to $t$, making it difficult to call it an "Ito integral" as it cannot be computed by ito's lemma.
Ultimately CLT determines everything.

In general Ito integrals are just local martingales.
